# I have installed Java successfully (i hope) and then i moved on installing Eclipse Neon. Neon isnt running and it produces these errors

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-neon

"Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\client\jvm.dll"

How do i fix this error

Comment: I did. 64-bit. P

Answer (score -1):

Did you install JDK correctly based on whether 32bit/64bit?

[JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)